# Assign windows server DNS to a domain

Tags: dns, windows-server-2016

I have a domain I bought from namecheap.com and I have a web server an AD along with a DNS I host at home. How do I setup my DNS at home so I to point my thomp.site domain from namecheap to my home DNS.

EDIT: I created a dynamic DNS with no-ip and I put that in as the one of the custom name servers on namecheap but when I type in my domain name (thomp.site) chrome says "The webpage at http://thomp.site/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

[For reference here is my Advanced DNS page of my domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW0cR.png)

Comment: Yeah i was about to edit and change my question

Comment: Are you talking about using your active directory DNS server and exposing it to the public internet?

Comment: Do you have a static or dynamic IP at home?  I think what you’re trying to do is point your domain name to home IP.  If that’s the case you may need a dynDNS or no-ip.com type of service if your home IP is dynamic (most are unless your isp offers static at a higher prices).  In any case the first step is to point the name to an IP, you’ll do that at namecheap.

Comment: @Tyson yes this was it, thank you for you help

Comment: Don't replace the nameservers on namecheap, just put an A record into your DNS on namecheap with the IP address of your no-ip domain name.

Comment: @varfirstName what do you mean by the IP address of no-ip domain, I made a url which is thompsite.ddns.net which points to my home external IP but where is the IP of my no-ip domain?

Comment: Oh dear I had a brainfart :( I meant a redirect record on Namecheap to the no-ip domain name.

Comment: @varfirstName ok, that makes more sense. So I put a URL redirect to my no-ip domain name that is masked?

Comment: you would either be able to use an A record to point to your home ip or a redirect record to your no-ip domain name. (thompsite.ddns.net)

Comment: Ok yeah I can see where to do that thank you for your help, I will let you know if I have anymore questions.

Comment: If this works, let me know and I'll post it as an answer :)

Comment: @varfirstName it worked! You can go ahead and post the answer for A records with my home ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not change your Namecheap domain's nameservers!

Instead, place an A (Address) type IN (INternet) record into your DNS on the Namecheap server, and point it to your home IP address!

You might also try a 301 Redirect record to your no-IP domain name :)